# gradle build for android native project fails with "unable to open output file" error

Tags: android, jenkins, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build an android native project using gradle. While the build passes for the architectures `arm64-v8a`, `x86` and `x86_64`, it fails for `armeabi-v7a` with a unique error:

```
/{sdk-path}/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=15 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -Os -DNDEBUG    -O2 -DNDEBUG -D_NDEBUG=1 -s -fPIC   -Wdeprecated-declarations -std=c++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/acplocalnet.dir/src/main/cpp/HttpTransferCallbackHookImpl.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/acplocalnet.dir/src/main/cpp/HttpTransferCallbackHookImpl.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/acplocalnet.dir/src/main/cpp/HttpTransferCallbackHookImpl.cpp.o -c /Users/acpl/workspace/ACPLocal_net_Android/net/project/android/acplocalnet/app/src/main/cpp/HttpTransferCallbackHookImpl.cpp
  clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-s' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  error: unable to open output file '/apps/temp/HttpTransferCallbackHookImpl-baaa5e.s': 'No such file or directory'
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The issue here is I am able to run this command and it builds the native libraries successfully when run the machine locally, but it fails when it is run through jenkins. The other amusing thing is that it fails only for the abi `armeabi-v7a` and passes for all other architectures.

I have verified the user, path and environment variables like *ANDROID_HOME* and *ANDROID_NDK_HOME* which are same when I run using the command line on the machine locally and when run using jenkins.

Comment: The command line that failed is cut (it should start with `{sdk-path}/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++` or similar).

Comment: Does the local build also warn about unused `-s` argument?

Comment: Yes it does. But anyways I found the issue. Jenkins was passing the temporary directory as /apps/tmp which was not present on the slave. But still it seems a bit strange that only arm7va build was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command was not able to open the output files in the location "/apps/temp" as this directory was not present in the slave. This temp directory present in the jenkins master and was passed to the slave which was visible in the build variable TMP_DIR. Explicitly mentioning a valid temporary directory for the jenkins slave fixed the issue.